# What does the @ at the end of access rights stand for?

Tags: macos, ls

When I ls -la, one of my folders has the following notation

drwxr-xr-x@ 28

what does @ stand for?

For the record, I am using OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the folder or file has extended attributes. use

```
xattr -l <filename>
```

to see them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Answer (score 1):

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l
>        option is followed by a '@' character.

[Reference to apple dev site for LS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html)